# reference a workbook vba index

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to reference workbooks with a loop.

```
Workbooks(iter2).Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = sh1.Cells(1, pre_fab_dtl - 4)
```

is how I am currently referencing it.

I would like to name it with the value of the variable "filename" where

```
filename = wb.cells(x,y)
```

but it apparently need the .xlsx at the end.

How would I reference this?

Comment: `filename = wb.cells(x,y) & ".xlsx"` and then `Workbooks(filename)`? Or you can add ".xlsx" in the cell value itself? Or have I understood your query incorrectly?

Comment: And if the workbook name is going to be unique then simply loop through the open workbooks and check using `LIKE` to find the relevant workbook and assign it to a workbook object. And then you can work with that workbook object

Answer (score 0):

I tackled this kind of situation recently.  I created a separate sub that was designed solely to open the workbook based on ranges and/or input.  Then that sub was run at the appropriate time.

```
            Sub wkbkOpen()
            'opens workbook based on user input, also stores as variables
            Dim fPath As String, fName As String, fType As String

            fPath = Range("FilePath")
            fName = Range("FileName")
            fType = Range("FileType")

              Range("M2").Value = fPath & fName & Format(dNum, "Fixed") & fType
              Set x = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fName & Format(dNum, "Fixed") & fType)
              Set y = Workbooks("Forecast-Storage_Monthly_v02.xlsm")

            End Sub
```

Basically, I handled each portion of the file name in a separate portion of a worksheet.